# Custom timestamp and windowing for Pub/Sub in DataFlow (Apache Beam)

Tags: java, python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I want to implement the following scenario using streaming pipeline in Apache Beam (and running it on Google DataFlow):

1. Read messages from Pub/Sub (JSON strings)
2. Deserialize JSONs
3. Use custom field (say `timeStamp`) as a timestamp value for the processing element
4. Apply fixed windowing of `60 seconds`
5. Extract key from elemtents and group by key
6. << perform further processing >>

I've tried to resolve this problem using both Java(Scala) and Python, but non of the solution worked.

1. **Python solution**

```py
# p is beam.Pipeline()
_ = (p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="my_sub")
        | beam.Map(add_timestamping)
        | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
        | beam.Map(lambda elem: elem) # exracting the key somehow, not relevant here
        | beam.GroupByKey()
        # (...)
        | beam.io.WriteToPubSub("output_topic")
        )
p.run()
```

`add_timestamping` function as per [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements):

```py
def add_timestamping(elem):
    import json
    import apache_beam as beam
    msg = json.loads(elem)
    unix_timestamp = msg['timeStamp'] / 1000
    return beam.window.TimestampedValue(msg, unix_timestamp)
```

**Output of Python solution**:

1. When using `DirectRunner`, windows are emitted and the windowing itself is more-or-less appropriate, depending on the delay.
2. When using `DataFlowRunner`, **ALL messages are skipped** with counter appearing in DataFlow UI: *droppedDueToLateness*.

---

2. **Java / Scala solution**
   (I've used *Scio* but this happens to in clean Beam SDK in Java too)

```scala
sc.pubsubSubscription[String]("my_sub")
    .applyTransform(ParDo.of(new CustomTs()))
    .withFixedWindows(Duration.standardSeconds(60))
    .map(x => x) // exracting the key somehow, not relevant here
    .groupByKey
    // (...)
    .saveAsPubsub("output_topic")
```

Adding custom timestamp as per [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#adding-timestamps-to-a-pcollections-elements):

```
import io.circe.parser._
class CustomTs extends DoFn[String, String] {
  @ProcessElement
  def processElement(@Element element: String, out: DoFn.OutputReceiver[String]): Unit = {
    val json = parse(element).right.get
    val timestampMillis: Long = json.hcursor.downField("timeStamp").as[Long].getOrElse(0)
    out.outputWithTimestamp(element, new Instant(timestampMillis))
  }
}
```

**Output of Java / Scala solution**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 Cannot output with timestamp 2019-03-02T00:51:39.124Z. 
 Output timestamps must be no earlier than the timestamp of the current input
 (2019-03-28T14:57:53.195Z) minus the allowed skew (0 milliseconds).
```

I cannot use `DoFn.getAllowedTimestampSkew` here as it's already deprecated and I don't know what ranges of historical data will be sent.

---

Having the ability to process historical data is crucial for my project (this data will be sent to Pub/Sub from some store). The pipeline must work both on current data as well as historical one.

My question is:
**How to process the data using custom timestamps with the ability to operate on windows defined using Beam API?**

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to extract the timestamp at insertion point to PubSub, you will be able to make use of user-specified timestamps as metadata. The information on how to is documented under the 1.9 SDK.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#timestamps-and-record-ids

"You can use user-specified timestamps for precise control over how elements read from Cloud Pub/Sub are assigned to windows in a Dataflow pipeline. "

As 1.9 is deprecated, in 2.11 you will need https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withTimestampAttribute-java.lang.String-

Comment: This is deprecated

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.Read.html#withTimestampAttribute-java.lang.String- should be the 2.11 version of the same bit as was available for 1.9 I think.

Comment: Using this method have you also set withAllowedLateness with your dataset?

Comment: I want to extract the timestamp from Pub/Sub message payload, not attribute.

Comment: + I've tried using "timestampAttribute" along with "withAllowedLateness" and it didn't work (at least for direct runner)

Comment: This seems to be relevant and provides a solution: https://medium.com/@erik.b.ferm/combining-bounded-pcollections-with-custom-timestamps-in-apache-beam-b0fd911b2ac

Comment: I saw that post but as you can see it's about bounded collections, whereas Pub/Sub is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to custom the timestamp of PubSub message through  `withAllowedTimestampSkew` of `WithTimestamps`

```java
 static SerializableFunction<Event, Instant> timestampFn = (Event input) -> new Instant(Objects.requireNonNull(input).getTs());

...

 PCollection<String> rawMessage = pipeline.apply("Read PubSub Message",
                        PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(topic)); 
 PCollection<Event> events = rawMessage.apply("Convert to UserEvent",
                MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(Event.class))
                        .via(Event::fromJSON))
                .apply("With Timestamp", WithTimestamps.of(timestampFn).withAllowedTimestampSkew(Duration.standardMinutes(2)));

 PCollection<Event> minute_window_events = events.apply("Minute Window",
                Window.<Event>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(3)))
                        .triggering(AfterProcessingTime
                                .pastFirstElementInPane()
                                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))
                        .discardingFiredPanes()
                        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(1))
        );
...
```

However, this method `withAllowedTimestampSkew` will be deprecated per doc

> @deprecated This method permits a to elements to be emitted behind the watermark. These
> elements are considered late, and if behind the {@link Window#withAllowedLateness(Duration)
> allowed lateness} of a downstream {@link PCollection} may be silently dropped. See
> https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/18065 for details on a replacement.

You could refer to https://github.com/apache/beam/issues/18065 for details on a replacement.

---

Another solution is `withTimestampAttribute`. You can set an attribute in pubsub messages that contains the `timestamp` field.

When publishing a message to PubSub

```java
p.apply(PubsubIO.writeString().withTimestampAttribute("timestamp").to(topic));
```

And when Subscribing:

```
p.apply(PubsubIO.readString().fromTopic(topic).withTimestampAttribute("timestamp"))
```